# Does the derivative exist?

Tags: derivatives

So I have this question here:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}+\frac{1}{1+|x-a|},a>0$

I am asked to find the derivative and I correctly found it as:

$f'(x)=-\frac{x-a}{|x-a|(|x-a|+1)^2}-\frac{x}{|x|(|x|+1)^2},a>0$

I am then asked to determine if $f'(0)$ and $f'(a)$ exist.

My understanding is that they don't exist because the derivative of $|x|$and$|x-a|$ don't exist at 0 and a by the definition of the derivative (There is a corner at those particular points.)

Is that correct? Or am I making a mistake?

Comment: is your argument that if you naively plug in $0$ or $a$ in your formula for $f'(x)$ you get nonsense? Because this argument is invalid.

Comment: Simplify the problem to understand better: first examine the derivative at $x = 0$ of the simpler function
$$
f(x) = {1 \over 1 + |x|}.
$$
Graph it, study it in a neighborhood of $x$, until you have a clear and detailed understanding of its structure.

Comment: @Takhteh_pareh  it is definded in $0$, $f(0)=1+\frac{1}{1+|a|}$.

Comment: No I wasn't thinking about it that way M. Van. I tried to consider the behavior of the graph.

Comment: try to determine the limit

Comment: User, if I try to look at the graph of the simpler function, there is a cusp at x=0. The derivative can't possibly exist there right? M. Van, if I take the limit, then the function is still well defined. It is not indeterminate or undefined anywhere. Why is that significant?

Comment: FURTHER EDIT: If I try to use he definition at a point, everything sill works out. Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that:
$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
This approach looks more promising. Now divide the problem into simpler parts to see what's going on. For example, let $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ and $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$. Then:
$$\begin{align}h'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\frac{1}{1+|x-a|}-1}{x-a}&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}\left(\frac{-1}{1+|x-a|}\right)\\&=-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}
\end{align}$$
You see that if you approach $a$ from the left you will get $+1$ and if you approach it from the right you'll get $-1$. Hence $h'(a)$ does not exist, whereas $g'(a)$ does exist. This implies $f'(a)$ does not exist. Because if it existed, $h'(a)=f'(a)-g'(a)$ and you would get a contradiction.

The same statement goes for $g'(x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get the rest of it on my own. Appreciate the help.